# show a drop down list from 2 dimensional tuple

Tags: python, django

I have a list of countries in a file as follows,

```
COUNTRIES = (
    ('AF', 'Afghanistan'),
    ('AX', '\xc5land Islands'),
    ('AL', 'Albania'),...
```

I would like to display only the full names of countries in my drop down list and also save only the full name in the model.

Right now my models.py is

```
class UserProfiles(models.Model):
   location = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
```

and forms.py is

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    location = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COUNTRIES)
```

Comment: If I got your question correctly, won't this work?

COUNTRIES = (
    ('Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan'),
    ('\xc5land Islands', '\xc5land Islands'),
    ('Albania', 'Albania'),...

Comment: This is not the solution, but UserProfileForm is not necessary. You can have something like this:                                    class UserProfiles(models.Model):
   location = models.CharField(max_length=60, choices=COUNTRIES, blank=True, null=True)

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the COUNTRIES list like this

```
COUNTRIES = [ (long, long) for short, long in COUNTRIES ]
```

Then use this in your model

```
class UserProfiles(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True, choices=COUNTRIES)
```

The form should be OK as it is